# package java.net.http does not exist for JDK 11

Tags: java, android, java-11

I don't know what's wrong as there is no error in my code but build failed with error package java.net.http does not exist.
I downloaded the jar and added it as dependency.
It also listed in java --list-modules.

- compileSdkVersion 32
- buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
- minSdkVersion 26
- targetSdkVersion 30
- gradleVersion = '7.2'
- sourceCompatibility
- JavaVersion.VERSION_11
- targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
- implementation files('libs/java.net.http.jar')

The jar I got from jmods folder in jdk folder.
I tried update to jdk 17 also same.
I try solution from this ["package java.net.http does not exist" error on JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910746/package-java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk9) but return module not found.
My impacted code

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(new URI(reqURI))
                    .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, 
HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println("uri:" + response.uri());
System.out.println("header:" +response.headers());
System.out.println("body" + response.body());
System.out.println("status code" + response.statusCode());
```

java -version:

- openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
- OpenJDK Runtime
  Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build
  11+28, mixed mode)

Inside build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation files('libs/simple-xml-2.6.7/simple-xml-2.6.7.jar')
implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/org-apache-commons-io/org-apache-commons-io.jar')
implementation files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/java.net.http.jar')
}
```

Actually, what I want is to replace below code which already deprecated

```
 DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
params = new BasicHttpParams();

params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000)
        .setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE,8*1024)
        .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK,false)
        .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true)
        .setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.ORIGIN_SERVER,"HttpComponents/1.1");
conn.bind(socket, params);
```

Extracting the information from the requested URI

```
HttpRequest request = conn.receiveRequestHeader();
request.getRequestLine().getMethod().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.getRequestLine().getUri());
String httpAPI = uri.getPath();
String httpQuery = uri.getQuery();
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676851/java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk11

Comment: have you tried this answer in the question you linked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910746/package-java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk9/43111760#43111760

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["package java.net.http does not exist" error on JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910746/package-java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk9)

Comment: what class are you trying to use? from where you get the error? please add information on how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @alirezafnatica yes, already checked that out. My java version openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode) meanwhile my android studio is the latest version.

Comment: @Tschallacka yup already tried, as per in that answer, incubator has been removed since 9, mine is 11. I added the "import java.net.http.HttpClient;" successfully. only failed when building it. not sure why.

Comment: @eis adding code. Basically I just want to do http request. I added java.net.http jar file as dependency and my code recognize it. But somehow when building the app, it thrown "package java.net.http is not exists"

Comment: So ... are you trying to build an app to run on Android?  Or to run on a Java SE platform?  In the former case ... why are you using `java.net.http` which is not an Android native API?  In the latter case, why are you using Android Studio and why do you have dependencies on androidx, etcetera?

Comment: If you are building for Android and *"just want to do an HTTP request"* is your complete list of relevant requirements, then I suggest using a Android native API; e.g. [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley).

Comment: @StephenC however, I read Volley wasn't suitable for streaming. This app intent to streaming live video; from android phone to web server.

Comment: “I downloaded the jar” what jar? From where?

Comment: @Holger I downloaded jdk11 and get java.net.http.jmods, change jmods to jar then add dependency to that jar file

Comment: A jmod is not a jar file. Both are zip containers, but they have a different directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by change the app’s targetSdkVersion and CompileSdkVersion (refer to [Migrating apps to Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/migration)), else there’ll be a lot of deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

For those using maven remember to upgrade the release # in pom.xml

I had the same symptom
[ERROR] ... .java:[5,21] package java.net.http does not exist
[ERROR] ... .java:[144,27] package HttpRequest does not exist
Upgraded from Java 16 to 18, updated JAVA_HOME, rebooted -  no joy
Realized the maven pom.xml might be outdated -
it was release 10, updated release # to match JDK 18
Solved, now compiles fine.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <release>18</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```